# A cube and a sphere have equal volume. What is the ratio of their surface areas?

Tags: geometry, volume, spheres

The answer is supposed to be $$ \sqrt[3]{6} : \sqrt[3]{\pi} $$

Since $$ \ a^3 = \frac{4}{3} \pi r^3  $$
I have expressed it as: $$ \ a = \sqrt[3]{ \frac{4}{3} \pi r^3} $$

and,

$$  \ 6 \left( \sqrt[3]{ \frac{4}{3} \pi r^3 } \right) ^2 : 4 \pi r^2 $$

But I am not really sure how to arrive at the desired result. I have tried to simplify it, but apparently I am missing some step in the process and come to a result that is far from the correct one.

Could you please help? Thank you.

Comment: Use identity $$\sqrt[3]{xy}=\sqrt[3]{x}\cdot\sqrt[3]{y}$$

Comment: Your result agrees with the expected answer! Try simplifying it again.

Comment: Well $\sqrt[3]{r^3}^2 = r^2$ so that factors out.  $\pi = \sqrt[3]{\pi}^3$ so that factors out of the left side leaving $\sqrt[3]{\pi}$ on the right. The 6 and the 4 can be divided by 2. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sphere with equal volume to a cube of side $a$ must have radius $r$:

$$\frac{4\pi r^3}{3} = a^3$$

So

$$r = \sqrt[3]{\frac{3}{4 \pi}}a$$

Now just take

$$\frac{4\pi r^2}{6a^2} = \frac{4\pi\sqrt[3]{\frac{9}{16 \pi^2}}a^2}{6a^2} = \frac{2}{3}\pi\sqrt[3]{\frac{9}{16 \pi^2}} = \sqrt[3]{\frac{9\cdot 8 \pi^3}{27 \cdot 16 \pi^2}} = \sqrt[3]{\pi/6}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach this is to write the surface areas of each solid in terms of its volume:

**cube --** $$ S_c \ = \ 6 \ a^2 \ \ , \ \ V_c \ = \ a^3 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ a \ = \ V_c^{1/3} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ S_c \ = \ 6 \ (V^{1/3})^2 \ = \ 6 \ V_c^{2/3} \ \ ; $$

**sphere --** $$ S_s \ = \ 4 \ \pi  \ r^2 \ \ , \ \ V_s \ = \ \frac{4}{3}  \ \pi \ r^3 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ r \ = \ \left(\frac{3 \ V_s}{4 \ \pi} \right)^{1/3} $$ $$ \Rightarrow \ \ S_s \ = \ 4 \ \pi \ \left[\left(\frac{3 \ V_s}{4 \ \pi} \right)^{1/3} \right]^2 \ = \ (4 \ \pi)^{1/3} \cdot 3^{2/3} \cdot V_s^{2/3} \ = \ \ (36 \ \pi)^{1/3} \ V_s^{2/3} \ \ . $$

The ratio of the surface areas is then

$$ \frac{S_c}{S_s} \ \ = \ \ \frac{6 \ V_c^{2/3}}{(36 \ \pi)^{1/3} \ V_s^{2/3}} \ \  ; $$

upon equating the volumes, we have

$$ \frac{S_c}{S_s} \ \ = \ \ \frac{6 \ V ^{2/3}}{(36 \ \pi)^{1/3} \ V ^{2/3}} \ \  = \ \ \frac{6   }{6^{2/3} \ \pi^{1/3} } \ \ = \ \ \left(\frac{6   }{  \pi  } \right)^{1/3} \ \ = \ \ \frac{6^{1/3}   }{  \pi^{1/3}  } \ \ \text{or} \ \ \frac{\sqrt[3]{6}   }{ \sqrt[3]{ \pi}  } \ \ .  $$

Answer (score 0):

Unit volume assumed:
$$
1 = \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3 = a^3
$$
So we have
$$
r = \sqrt[3]{\frac{3}{4\pi}}  \\
\quad a = 1
$$
So the surface ratio is
$$
A_s = 4 \pi r^2 
= 4 \pi \left( \frac{3}{4\pi} \right)^{2/3}
= \sqrt[3]{4\pi \cdot 9} 
=\sqrt[3]{\pi} \, 6^{2/3} \\
A_c = 6
$$
So we get
$$
A_s : A_c = 
\sqrt[3]{\pi} : \sqrt[3]{6}
$$

Answer (score 0):

For convenience, we will compare two shapes of volume $\dfrac16$.

For a cube, $V=\dfrac16=c^3,S=6c^2$, so that $S=6^{1/3}$.

For a sphere, $V=\dfrac16=\dfrac43\pi r^3,S=4\pi r^2$ so that $S=4\pi\left(\dfrac1{8\pi}\right)^{2/3}=\pi^{1/3}$.